# How do I pass a Telegram bot CommandHandler message to my function?

Tags: python, bots, telegram

Example messages

- /weather 90210
- /weather Beverley Hills, CA, US

My CommandHandler is as follows:

```
weather_hanlder = CommandHandler('weather', weather_get_results)
dp.add_handler(weather_handler)
```

I want everything after /weather to be passed to my weather_get_results(PASS STRING IN HERE) function.

I have looked through telegram's documentation and examples and haven't had much luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

So, the arguments are actually in the context parameter passed to the callback!

context.args specifically; it's the list of arguments you send through with the command. in your example, context.args[0] would be 'Beverley'.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably the wrong way to do this but I managed to find the data in update...

```
def weather_get_results(update, context):
    weather_command_text = update['message']['text'][9::]
    weather_search = weather_command_text
```